# string transmission using MSP EXP430F5438

Tags: msp430

I am using MSP - EX430F5438 and CC2520EM, I am able to send integral data but I am not able to send string of characters.

When I send any string I see the string being sent from transmitter but on receiver side I receive something random ount: .

I also tried converting the characters in the string to ascii code and then send it but I am not able to convert it properly , i.e. any string gets converted to same integral value 23316.( Although I am successfully able to convert a single character into ascii code and send it successfully).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a problem with the data type definition or the data itself.

Take a look at both ends of the transmission, you don't say what's the transmitter. If it's another MSP+CC this might not be the case, but if you are using a different transmitter and language maybe you are using incompatible data types.

Keep in mind your MSP uses C and a string in C is just an array of chars. If you are using, for instance, java at the other side, you will have to translate your java string to an array of bytes and send these bytes in the message. From that point on you should be receiving the chars and may have some problems with the encoding, but nothing you cannot work out.

Hope this helps.

Maybe I could help more if I knew more about the transmitter and the communication stack you are using.